# Distribute items based on the time duration

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

I just finished a small assignment and I would like to get some feedback about the implementation here. Basically, it was all about distributing items ("talks" in this case) throughout the day based on the time constraints (their duration). For instance, a given place have different "tracks" each of which has a *morning* (9AM - 12PM) and *afternoon* (1PM - 5PM) session.

> The input data is a file with this structure: `Talk Name XYmin` (where `XY` are positive numbers).

This is what I came up with (I know it's a little bit silly but I guess it works for the most part):

```java
public final class Conference {
  private static final long MORNING_SPAN = 180; // 09:00 AM - 12:00PM

  private static final long AFTERNOON_SPAN = 240; // 01:00 PM - 05:00 PM

  private final List<Talk> talks;

  private final List<Track> tracks;

  private final long numberOfTracks;

  public Conference(final List<Talk> talks) {
    final var duration = talks.stream().mapToLong(Talk::duration).sum();
    final var daySpan = MORNING_SPAN + AFTERNOON_SPAN;
    this.talks = talks;
    numberOfTracks = duration / daySpan + (duration % daySpan == 0L ? 0L : 1L);
    tracks = new LinkedList<>();
  }

  public List<Track> getTracks() { return tracks; }

  public void displaySchedule() {
    if (tracks.isEmpty()) {
      makeSchedule();
    }
    // More System.out.println statements for the required output
  }

  private void makeSchedule() { // ...this one is the deal!
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTracks; i++) {
      final var morning = new LinkedList<Talk>();
      final var afternoon = new LinkedList<Talk>();
      var morningSpan = MORNING_SPAN;
      var afternoonSpan = AFTERNOON_SPAN;
      final var iterator = talks.iterator();
      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        final var talk = iterator.next();
        if (talk.duration() <= morningSpan) {
          morning.add(talk);
          morningSpan -= talk.duration();
          iterator.remove();
        } else if (talk.duration() <= afternoonSpan) {
          afternoon.add(talk);
          afternoonSpan -= talk.duration();
          iterator.remove();
        }
      }
      tracks.add(new Track(morning, afternoon));
    }
  }
}
```

```java
public final class Talk {
  public final String title;

  public final String duration;

  public Talk(final String title, final String duration) {
    this.title = title;
    this.duration = duration;
  }

  public long duration() {
    if ("lightning".equalsIgnoreCase(duration)) {
      return Constant.LIGHTNING;
    }
    // Basically this returns the duration for the talk (as long)...that's it
    return Long.parseLong(Constant.NON_NUMBERS.matcher(duration).replaceAll(""));
  }
}
```

```java
public final class Track {
  private final List<Talk> morning;

  private final List<Talk> afternoon;

  public Track(final List<Talk> morning, final List<Talk> afternoon) {
    this.morning = morning;
    this.afternoon = afternoon;
  }

  // Some more stuff here to display the required output
}
```

The real deal here is `Conference::makeSchedule` — that's where I would like to know if there is a better, more efficient way to approach this solution...probably using different data structures, etc. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice implementation, it's well structured and easy to understand. Few general suggestions:

- **`int` instead of `long`**: the constants `MORNING_SPAN` and `AFTERNOON_SPAN` contain minutes in a day, using an `int` is enough.
- **Input validation**: the talk duration needs to be validated. If the talk duration is greater than `MORNING_SPAN` or `AFTERNOON_SPAN` it won't be included in any track. If it's negative it will also lead to issues. In the `Conference` class ensure that the list `talks` is not empty.
- **Creating the schedule**: I see that the schedule is created (lazily) in the `displaySchedule` method of `Conference`. I think that creating the schedule is an important action, it can be the responsibility of another class, like `ScheduleMaker`. Then, the list of tracks can be added to `Conference` in the constructor.
- **`Talk` interface**: `talk.duration` returns a string like "30min", while `talk.duration()` returns `30` as a `long`. I find it a bit confusing. If you need both, consider creating two different variables and two getters. Otherwise, parse the duration in the constructor and use only the `long` value.

### Bin packing problem

Let's consider this example:

```
morning_span = 2m (2 minutes)
afternoon_span = 1m
daily_span = morning_span + afternoon_span = 3m

talk1 = 2m
talk2 = 2m
talk3 = 2m
total_talks_duration = 6m
```

Calling `conference.makeSchedule()` will result in:

```
numberOfTracks = total_talks_duration / daily_span = 6 / 3 = 2

Schedule:
Track1 = talk1 (morning)
Track2 = talk2 (morning)
talk3 ??
```

As you can see the current `makeSchedule` will create two tracks, but `talk3` won't be included.

This bug can be fixed by running the other loop till all the talks are placed:

```
private void makeSchedule() {
    while (talks.size() > 0) {
        // Create a new track
        // Add in the track as many talks as possible
        // Remove talks added to the current track
    }
}
```

Now all talks will be placed in the tracks, however, there are cases where the algorithm will create more tracks than needed. This is considered a [Bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem#CITEREFMartelloToth1990). Basically, fit the talks in the minimum number of tracks. Interestingly, my university professor developed an [exact algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem#Exact_algorithm) for this problem ([pdf](http://www.or.deis.unibo.it/kp/Chapter8.pdf)). I'll leave it to you for additional study.

Comment: That's great feedback. I didn't know about the `Bin packing problem`! Let me try to incorporate those suggestions — this time just for myself, but it's always nice to make it better!